# Union Select Only One Row

Tags: sql

I Have a query with Two Select Clause combines with UNION.I want to select only top first row. How can i do that Using Union ?

```
Select Fault,OccurredOn From ATMStatus Where Ticket=189703 // This Will retrieve single record as the primary key is applied
Union 
Select Fault,OccurredOn From ATMStatusHistory Where Resolved=0 AND Ticket=189703 Order By OccurredOn Desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select top 1 * from 
(
                 Select Fault,OccurredOn 
                 From ATMStatus
                 Where Ticket=189703
                 Union 
                 Select Fault,OccurredOn
                 From ATMStatusHistory
                 Where Resolved=0 AND Ticket=189703
) x
Order By OccurredOn Desc
```

Comment: Invalid Column name OccuredOn

Comment: This is very odd. See [this simplified example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eece/1)

Answer (score 0):

This returns 2 rows:

```
select 1 as id
union
select 2 as id
```

This returns 1 row:

```
select top 1 * from (
  select 1 as id
  union
  select 2 as id
) as x
order by id
```

Comment: Which row (1 or 2) is returned is, of course, not defined in this query.

Comment: You're right -- fixed.  I'd edit it to include the OP query too, but then it would look like I just copied the answer from 'juergen d'...