# how fast ist it in sql if I would select only the first row with four selects

Tags: sql, select, union

I'v a problem with look like the same as [Union Select Only One Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845702/union-select-only-one-row/)
But with little different. I'v four selects combined with the union statment.

```
select top 1 value from (
    select 1 as id, value from resource where rkey = 'a'
    union
    select 2 as id, value from resource where rkey = 'b'
    union
    select 3 as id, value from resource where rkey = 'c'
    union
    select 4 as id, value from resource where rkey = 'd'
) as x
order by id
```

Each of the select statement gives only one or zero rows back. I already would use the first result of all selects. So if the first select returns one row then the other selects should be ignored. And if the second select gives the row back (the first select gives no row back) then the others should be ignored. etc...

My question is: **How fast is it in this combination or is there a faster solution?**

Comment: UNION ALL is usually faster than UNION.

Comment: This is unanswerable: it depends on the database, the table structure the actual data, the way it is stored, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `key` is indexed your approach (but using `UNION ALL`) might be the best.

Otherwise try:

```
select top 1 value 
from resource 
where rkey in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
order by 
  case rkey 
    when 'a' then 1
    when 'b' then 2
    when 'c' then 3
    when 'd' then 4
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Or skip the `UNION`:

```
select top 1 value
from resource 
where rkey in ('a','b','c','d')
order by rkey
```