# SQL Union SELECT from two tables then combine to one row

Tags: mysql, union, recursive-query

I have two tables (tests and reserved) which reference each other it is a 1:1 relationship.

One test's ID is reserved for another test's ID which is in the same table but kept in the reserved table as a look up.

Here's some sample data:

tests:

```
test_id | summary_id | ref
    1   |     1      | ref1
    2   |     2      | ref2
```

reserved:

```
reserved_id | reserved_summary_id | reserved_for_summary_id
        1   |           1         |           2
```

Currently I am using a UNION to get them both:

```
SELECT * FROM reserved r, tests t WHERE t.summary_id = r.reserved_summary_id
UNION
SELECT * FROM reserved r, tests t WHERE t.summary_id = r.reserved_for_summary_id
```

I have a [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43e716/1).

How can I combine that query into one row? I have tried this one from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845702/union-select-only-one-row). But get an error.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Why do you have such a weird table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to `JOIN` the summary table twice with the the `tests` table so you can access the details of each `reserved_summary` and `reserved_for_summary` ?

If yes, then you need :

```
SELECT
    r.reserved_id,
    t1.ref ref_of_reserved_summary_id,
    t2.ref ref_of_reserved_for_summary_id
FROM 
    reserved r
    INNER JOIN tests t1 ON t1.summary_id = r.reserved_summary_id
    INNER JOIN tests t2 ON t2.summary_id = r.reserved_for_summary_id
```

This will return something like :

```
reserved_id | ref_of_reserved_summary_id | ref_of_reserved_for_summary_id
        1   |           ref1             |           ref2
```

You can switch to `LEFT JOIN` to avoid filtering out records where one of the summaries is not registered in the tests table.

Comment: yes this is perfect and is what I needed, thank you also for the Left join tip. A side question is this a recursive query?

Comment: @AbuNooh : welcome ! No this query is not recursive, it just uses two simple joins.

Comment: I'm not familiar with recursive queries but wondered because it was looking back at the same table. Thanks again!

Comment: @AbuNooh : FYI, recursion comes into play when you have a *hierarchical* structure, like parent > child > grandchild > ...

Comment: Thought I did it already but hadn't nonetheless just did it now!